# OpenCV triangulation with 3 cameras

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, triangulation, pose

I am conducting an experiment where I have 3 fixed cameras synchronized to record an individual evolving in a limited space (which is entirely coverd by the field of each camera). I use a pre-trained AI model to detect more than 20 pose landmarks at every frame, representing hundreds of 2D points in each video. My goal is to represent these landmarks as a 3D point cloud using OpenCV (Python).
I know this is feasible in the case of 2 cameras using cv2.triangulatePoints(). I used this method to obtain one 3D point set for each possible cameras pair (camera 1 - camera 2, camera 2 - camera 3, ...). But it seems that these sets cannot easily be merged together because they are expressed in different coordinates systems.
How can I "triangulate" 3D points using the data from the 3 cameras, rather than an arbitrary pair of them?

I tried to merge the 3D sets by using the extrinsic matrices obtained through cv2.recoverPose(), just to realize that this is not feasible. I then ran cv2.solvePnP() and got rotation and translation matrices, but do not know exactly what to make of them.

Here is the type of code I use:

```
def getProjectionMat(pts_l, pts_r, K_l, K_r):
    pts_l_norm = cv2.undistortPoints(np.expand_dims(pts_l, axis=1), cameraMatrix=K_l, distCoeffs=None)
    pts_r_norm = cv2.undistortPoints(np.expand_dims(pts_r, axis=1), cameraMatrix=K_r, distCoeffs=None)
    E, mask = cv2.findEssentialMat(pts_l_norm, pts_r_norm, focal=1.0, pp=(0., 0.), method=cv2.RANSAC, prob=0.999, threshold=3.0)
    points, R, t, mask = cv2.recoverPose(E, pts_l_norm, pts_r_norm)
    M_r = np.hstack((R, t))
    M_l = np.hstack((np.eye(3, 3), np.zeros((3, 1))))
    P_l = np.dot(K_l,  M_l)
    P_r = np.dot(K_r,  M_r)
    return P_l, P_r, R, t  
    
def get3DPoints(points1, points2, P1, P2):
    point_4d_hom = cv2.triangulatePoints(P1, P2, np.expand_dims(points1, axis=1), np.expand_dims(points2, axis=1))
    point_4d = point_4d_hom / np.tile(point_4d_hom[-1, :], (4, 1))
    return point_4d[:3, :].T

#ptpL1 are 2D points of camera 1, ptpL2 are corresponding points in camera 2, etc.
#K1, K2, etc. are intrinsic matrices

P1_1, P2_1, xR1, xt1=getProjectionMat(ptpL1, ptpL2, K1, K2) #projection between cams 1 and 2
P1_2, P2_2, xR2, xt2=getProjectionMat(ptpl2, ptpl3, K2, K3) #... between cams 2 and 3
P1_3, P2_3, xR3, xt3=getProjectionMat(ptpl1, ptpL3, K1, K3) #... between cams 1 and 3

#get2DPointForCam(x, markOfInterest) returns the 2D coordinates of the given landmark for cam x

for markOfInterest in marksOfInterest:
    point2D1=get2DPointForCam(1, markOfInterest)
    point2D2=get2DPointForCam(2, markOfInterest)
    point2D3=get2DPointForCam(3, markOfInterest)
    point3D1=get3DPoints(point2D1, point2D2, P1_1, P2_2)[0]
    point3D2=get3DPoints(point2D2, point2D3, P1_2, P2_2)[0]
    point3D3=get3DPoints(point2D1, point2D3, P1_3, P2_3)[0]

    #problem : point3D1 and point3D3 are close, but point3D2 has a completely different value. Still, when projected onto camera2, it is well positionned.
```

UPDATE : following @Micka suggestion, I (re)tried to use solvePNP to compute each camera relative position to some pose markers. I was hoping that this would allow me to convert to triangulation of each pairs of cameras into a common coordinate system. However, this fails again (see following code where problematic results are commented):

```
def getProjectionMat(pts_l, pts_r, K_l, K_r):
    pts_l_norm = cv2.undistortPoints(np.expand_dims(pts_l, axis=1), cameraMatrix=K_l, distCoeffs=None)
    pts_r_norm = cv2.undistortPoints(np.expand_dims(pts_r, axis=1), cameraMatrix=K_r, distCoeffs=None)
    E, mask = cv2.findEssentialMat(pts_l_norm, pts_r_norm, focal=1.0, pp=(0., 0.), method=cv2.RANSAC, prob=0.999, threshold=3.0)
    points, R, t, mask = cv2.recoverPose(E, pts_l_norm, pts_r_norm)
    M_r = np.hstack((R, t))
    M_l = np.hstack((np.eye(3, 3), np.zeros((3, 1))))
    P_l = np.dot(K_l,  M_l)
    P_r = np.dot(K_r,  M_r)
    return P_l, P_r, R, t  
    
def triangulate3DPoints(points1, points2, P1, P2):
    point_4d_hom = cv2.triangulatePoints(P1, P2, np.expand_dims(points1, axis=1), np.expand_dims(points2, axis=1))
    point_4d = point_4d_hom / np.tile(point_4d_hom[-1, :], (4, 1))
    return point_4d[:3, :].T

def getPoseMatrixFromPNP(points3D, points2D, K):
    _, vector_rotation, vector_translation = cv2.solvePnP(np.array(points3D), np.array(points2D), K, np.zeros((4,1)), flags=0)
    matrix_rotation, _ = cv2.Rodrigues(vector_rotation)
    return np.linalg.inv(np.vstack((np.hstack((matrix_rotation, vector_translation)), np.array([[0,0,0,1]]))))

def toHomogenous(vec):
    return np.array([vec[0], vec[1], vec[2], 1])

def project_3D_point_to_2D(point_3D, P):
    point_3D_homogeneous = np.hstack((point_3D, np.ones(1)))
    point_2D_homogeneous = np.dot(P, point_3D_homogeneous.T).T
    point_2D = point_2D_homogeneous[:2] / point_2D_homogeneous[2]
    return point_2D

P1_1, P2_1, xR1, xt1=getProjectionMat(ptpL1, ptpL2, K1, K2)
P1_2, P2_2, xR2, xt2=getProjectionMat(ptpL2, ptpL3, K2, K3)
P1_3, P2_3, xR3, xt3=getProjectionMat(ptpL1, ptpL3, K1, K3)

marksOfInterest=[mp.solutions.pose.PoseLandmark.NOSE] #for example

#c12Dpoints, etc., will contain 2D coordinates of each landmark respectively for cam 1, 2 and 3
c12Dpoints=[]
c22Dpoints=[]
c32Dpoints=[]
#resTriangulated  will contain 3D coordinates of each landmark, as estimated using cv2.triangulatePoints() between cams 1 and 2
resTriangulated=[]
for markOfInterest in marksOfInterest:
    marks1=getSpecificLandMarks(landMarks1, markOfInterest)
    marks2=getSpecificLandMarks(landMarks2, markOfInterest)
    marks3=getSpecificLandMarks(landMarks3, markOfInterest)
    for idFrame, e1 in enumerate(marks1):
        e2 = marks2[idFrame]
        e3 = marks3[idFrame]
        if e1 is not None and e2 is not None and e3 is not None:
            p1=[[e1.x*width, e1.y*height]]
            p2=[[e2.x*width, e2.y*height]]
            p3=[[e3.x*width, e3.y*height]]
            triangulated=triangulate3DPoints(p1, p2, P1_1, P2_1)[0]
            resTriangulated.append(triangulated)
            c12Dpoints.append(p1)
            c22Dpoints.append(p2)
            c32Dpoints.append(p3)

pose1=getPoseMatrixFromPNP(resTriangulated, c12Dpoints, K1)
pose2=getPoseMatrixFromPNP(resTriangulated, c22Dpoints, K2)
pose3=getPoseMatrixFromPNP(resTriangulated, c32Dpoints, K3)

posList=[]
for markOfInterest in marksOfInterest:
    marks1=getSpecificLandMarks(landMarks1, markOfInterest)
    marks2=getSpecificLandMarks(landMarks2, markOfInterest)
    marks3=getSpecificLandMarks(landMarks3, markOfInterest)
    for idFrame, e1 in enumerate(marks1):
        e2 = marks2[idFrame]
        e3 = marks3[idFrame]
        if e1 is not None and e2 is not None and e3 is not None:
            p1=[[e1.x*width, e1.y*height]]
            p2=[[e2.x*width, e2.y*height]]
            p3=[[e3.x*width, e3.y*height]]
            triangulated1=triangulate3DPoints(p1, p2, P1_1, P2_1)[0]
            triangulated2=triangulate3DPoints(p2, p3, P1_2, P2_2)[0]
            triangulated3=triangulate3DPoints(p1, p3, P1_3, P2_3)[0]
            worldCoordP1=(pose1 @ toHomogenous(triangulated1).reshape(4,1).flatten())[:-1]
            worldCoordP2=(pose2 @ toHomogenous(triangulated2).reshape(4,1).flatten())[:-1]
            worldCoordP3=(pose1 @ toHomogenous(triangulated3).reshape(4,1).flatten())[:-1]
            #problem: worldCoordP2 is very different from worldCoordP1 and worldCoordP3 (the latter being quite different too). The three variables should be close as they represent the same point (although estimated differently) in the same coordinate system.
```

Comment: what have you tried so far ?
the question needs sufficient code for a minimal reproducible example:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @D.L thank you for the answer. I edited my post accordingly.

Comment: What do you mean by "frames" in "But it seems that these sets cannot easily be merged together because they are expressed in different frames"? Is it different time or coordinate systems or what do you mean?

Comment: @Micka thank you for pointing out the ambiguity. By "frames" I meant coordinate systems. Temporal synchronization is not a problem at all.

Comment: From your camera system calibration you should have extrinsics of your cameras in one common coordinate system (if you have 3 individual calibrations you will need another one). Transform a reconstructed 3D point with the extrinsics of its camera and you have that 3D point in the common coordinate system.

Comment: @Micka how exactly do you get extrinsic parameters in a common coordinate system? Is there any way that I did not implement in my getProjectionMat function?

Comment: For example place well detectable markers in the scene with known 3D positions, so that every camera can see enough of them. Then use solvePnp to get M, the marker pose in camera system. Then invert M to get the camera pose in marker coordinate system (which is your defined 3D space).

Comment: If there's enough overlap,a single checkerboard could be that markers. If there isnt enough overlap or too different angles, you will need multiple markers and you have to measure their positions.

Comment: @Micka thank you so much for the suggestion. However, this did not work as shows the last update of my post. Do you have any idea by chance?

Comment: Dont use your triangulated points for solvePnp but instead use a perfectly known calibration object for calibrating your camera extrinsics. In the case you dont have a static camera setup (e.g. moving cameras) change it to a static camera setup in your first tests, until you are certain that everything works as intended.

Comment: @Micka thank you very much. I understand now why my approach was not successful. I succeeded in getting correct poses for the camera by using theoretical 3D positions for the landmarks and considering that these theoretical positions were the real ones at the video frame where the landmarks are the most visible by the three cameras. Unfortunately I have a huge amount of already captured footage to treat so the positioning of physical markers is not possible. Would you have (again) any genius suggestion on a better method than the one I now use (theoretical positions)?

Comment: Sorry, I am not so experienced with 3D reconstruction. Maybe with much more details about your specific case, ecample data and much more time, I could give you ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if OpenCV has a ready to use function for this. Triangulation with multiple cameras is discussed in several computer vision books. E.g

Richard Szeliski, Computer Vision: Algorithms and Applications,
chapter 7.1 Triangulation

https://szeliski.org/Book/